# Customizing registration of new users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, registration

I'm having some trouble registering new users in Laravel. In my project users are registered by system admins only. The expected behavior is that after sending the form, the new user will be stored and the admin redirected back to the register page.

However, when the form is filled and sent, 1) the new user is not stored and 2) the admin gets redirected to the *homepage*.

From what I could gather, I can't use Laravel's `RegisterController` because it was meant for users to register themselves using the default register form.

How can I customize the registration of new users so admins can do it?

My `redirectTo()` method on `LoginController`:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
  if (auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
      $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
      return $this->redirectTo;
  }
  elseif (auth()->user()->role == 'professor') {
      $this->redirectTo = '/professor';
      return $this->redirectTo;
  }
  elseif (auth()->user()->role == 'student') {
      $this->redirectTo = '/student';
      return $this->redirectTo;
  }
  else {
    return '/';
  }
}
```

In `RegisterController` I simply added the `role` field:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'role' => 'required|in:admin,professor,aluno',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]);
}
```

However, using the default `RegisterController` like this doesn't work and the result in explained above.

Comment: Please share some code so the community can help you better. On the other hand, you should be able to create a user with the normal eloquent create() method.

Comment: @DiegoPonciano Sorry for the lack of info. I have added the code for my Register and Login controllers.

Comment: Ok that helps figure out where you are thanks, so you need to create a controller, a route, a view and I am guessing you already have the migration to add your role. The route you create will have to use a middleware to authorize only users with your admin role. All this is with the admin user already logged in using the default laravel auth form. You create a new page with a new form and you will need to perform form validation and after that register the new user from your controller, once you get to that point you will notice you have complete control of what happens from the controller.

Comment: @DiegoPonciano Yes, I have the view for the admin register page. The authorization system also works, I have three users (created with seeds) that are properly redirected. However, creating new users using the default RegisterController fails. If I understand correctly, I have to create a different controller to handle the registering of users from the admin area. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct you need a separate endpoint for that

Comment: Tell me please the full path of the RegisterController do you edit...

Comment: What do you mean with full path? You need to create that in your routes and also point it to your controller. I suggest you give a read to this part https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters and also everything under the "The basics" part of the docs. Or also laracasts.com is pretty neat.

Comment: @DiegoPonciano Thanks, I just got it to work with a separate controller :)